# React Native Debug (Chrome): "Activate Breakpoints" not working as expected

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, react-native

In a **React Native** project, I have some breakpoints (in Google Chrome DevTools).

I then decide to deactivate them and switch the "Activate Breakpoints" button to "blue" color:
[image]

...which works (no breakpoints are triggered while I continue running the application).

**However**, when I **reload** the application the breakpoints **do trigger** despite the *"non-activated"* flag exists:

[image]

This should not be happening.

The only way to ignore the breakpoints is:
- Activate them again
- Press F8 to continue
- Deactivate them
(then, the application continues running without breakpoints).

Is this a known bug? Do you also experience it and if yes is there any solution to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

RN developer tools are still in testing phase. For MAC they are more stable than comparing to windows. The reason is actually the bundling of assests and js files.
the console takes it as a single file and then distributes it to different files that are showing in the workingdebugger.js file.
So it recreates them every time you reload the app.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but why would the breakpoints exhibit this behavior? If they are deactivated they should just not be triggered on reload.

Do you experience this? If yes, is there any way to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Ankit is this still true? I am having many problems with breakpoints using Chrome and the React Dev Tools in windows.